# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]

Tags: php

### problemas al hacer múltiples insert en sql server

tengo un  problema al hacer múltiples insert into en  sql server . estoy trayendo  registros desde una API y los deseo guardar en una base de datos sql, hago un while

```
  $userArray = json_decode($queryUsersResul, true);

    $grupoArray=array($resultadoQuery,$userArray);

    $ajaxArrayUnido=json_encode($grupoArray);



        $i = 0;

        while ($i < count($grupoArray[0]['result'])) {

            $valor = $grupoArray[0]['result'][$i]['assigned_user_id'];

            $arrayRequest = $grupoArray[0]['result'][$i];

            $j = 0;

            while ($j < count($grupoArray[1]['result'])) {

                $arrayRequestUsers = $grupoArray[1]['result'][$j];

                if ($valor == $grupoArray[1]['result'][$j]['id']) {

                    $consulta = array(
                        $arrayRequest['id'],
                        $arrayRequest['quote_no'],
                        $arrayRequest['cf_1102'],
                        $arrayRequest['assigned_user_id'],
                        $arrayRequestUsers['user_name'],
                        $arrayRequest['cf_1104'],
                        $arrayRequest['cf_1106'],
                        $arrayRequest['cf_1112'],
                        $arrayRequest['cf_1192'],
                        $arrayRequest['cf_1196'],
                        $arrayRequest['cf_1200'],
                        $arrayRequest['cf_1249']
                    );

                     $insertarDatos = new Conexion();
                     $resultado=$insertarDatos->insertarApi($consulta);

                     if ($resultado){

                         echo 'correcto <br>'.$resultado;

                     }
                     else{
                         echo 'error ';

                     }


                 /* echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($consulta);
                    echo "</pre>";*/
                }

                $j++;

            }

            $i++;
        }
```

despues le envio  el array a mi class conexion

```
 public function insertarApi($query){

    $enviarQuery=$this->conexion;
    $resultado=$enviarQuery->prepare("insert into dbo.PRUEBA (idCotizacion,numeroCotizacion,asunto,idAsignadoPersona,asignadoPersona,alcanceInspeccion,ubicacionProyecto,visitas,aprobacionTecnico,nombreJefeTecnico,fechaAprovacion,observaciones)
     values(:idCotizacion,:numeroCotizacion,:asunto,:idAsignadoPersona,:asignadoPersona,:alcanceInspeccion,:ubicacionProyecto,:visitas,:aprobacionTecnico,:nombreJefeTecnico,:fechaAprovacion,:observaciones)");

    $resultado->execute(array(

        'idCotizacion'=>$query[0],
        'numeroCotizacion'=>$query[1],
        'asunto'=>$query[2],
        'idAsignadoPersona'=>$query[3],
        'asignadoPersona'=>$query[4],
        'alcanceInspeccion'=>$query[5],
        'ubicacionProyecto'=>$query[6],
        'visitas'=>$query[7],
        'aprobacionTecnico'=>$query[8],
        'nombreJefeTecnico'=>$query[9],
        'fechaAprovacion'=>$query[10],
        'observaciones'=>$query[11]

    ));

   return $resultado;

}
```

La cuestión es que si hay múltiples registros con llaves primarias repetidas  deberia no insertarlas y seguir con el siguiente registro. recorriendo el while .pero la cuestión es que se detiene al detectar el primer registro duplicado y no sigue con los demás registros, por ende no me inserta todos los datos necesarios.

En mysql si funciona perfecto. que debo hacer ???

Comment: me sale el siguiente error :Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Infracción de la restricción PRIMARY KEY 'PK__PRUEBA__D931C39BD4878801'. No se puede insertar una clave duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.PRUEBA'. El valor de la clave duplicada es (4x54177). in C:\xampp2\htdocs\API\Conexion.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\API\Conexion.php(49): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp2\htdocs\API\api.php(81): Conexion->insertarApi(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\API\Conexion.php on line 49

Comment: Realmente tienes un concepto errado cuando dices esto: *... si hay múltiples registros con llaves primarias repetidas deberia no insertarlas y seguir con el siguiente registro* No, no funciona así. Cuando intentas insertar un duplicado no salta porque sí, pasando a insertar el siguiente registro. Lo que debes hacer es verificar primero si el registro no existe antes de insertarlo, haciendo un `SELECT` que use como criterio los campos que son llave primaria o unique en la tabla. Deberías hacerlo así. Además los intentos fallidos de inserción hacen crecer el id autonumérico de la tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo tender presente . pero porque cuando realice el mismo proceso en mysql no paso esto y si registro los query?

Comment: Quizá porque la tabla que usaste en ese caso no tenía la restricción `UNIQUE` para esos campos. Si la tabla tiene esa restricción, uses lo que uses no te permitirá bajo ningún concepto insertar un duplicado. Es una restricción que existe a nivel de la base de datos, no tiene nada que ver con PDO, mysqli ... ni siquiera la consola misma de mysql. En cualquier escenario que intentes, si hay una restricción, impedirá que se inserten duplicados.

Comment: okey entiendo . muchas gracias por tu colaboración